# Changing the Interrupt Vector Table

Tags: cpu, operating-system, c, interrupt

During one of my university lectures we were talking about hooking and the possiblitity to change the interrupt vector table (IVT).

Our professor said that a program with root permissions is able to change the IVT and may use this ability e.g. as a key logger for every key press.

Does this mean that I can change with a e.g. C program my IVT ? Or how does it work ?

Comment: You can certainly do this in assembly language in DOS using real mode, on newer operating system you have to go through kernel.

Comment: Too broad. Not every architecture has a interrupt vector table or different privilege levels (actually most don't). But your prof is wrong even iff both are available and used by an OS. Or you missunderstood what he meant. You should ask her to clarify and provide more details.

Comment: Proof this is possible - http://nicolascormier.com/documentation/security/malicious-code-injection-via-dev-mem.pdf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *Interrupt Vector Table* is just an array of items<sup>1</sup> placed somewhere in memory. If your program has root privileges it can write to [`/dev/mem`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/mem.4.html) and change the contents of the *IVT*.

However tempering, the *IVT* is not evenly close to be enough to have a working hook: you have first to find the *IVT*<sup>2</sup> and then to compute the right value to put in it<sup>3</sup>.  Being root is often **not enough** though, you can temper the *IVT* with a C program but you may need to write a *Kernel Module* to have a [working hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245850/linux-ubuntu-c-language-virtual-to-physical-address-translation).

The very specific way of hooking the *IVT* is dependent on the architecture of choice, you can reference specific *CPU manuals* and platform *Datasheets* by simply Googling for them.

Hooking the *IVT* may be actually used as part of an [escalation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation) rather than adding functionality to the OS<sup>4</sup>.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>
*x86* use far pointers in *real mode* and *descriptors* in *protected and long mode*, *ARM* and *PowerPC* use instructions, *MIPS* doesn't really have an IVT.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>
In *x86* it can be anywhere, you would need to use the privileged instruction `lidt`. In *ARM* it can be at fixed locations or it can be moved through the use of registers like `VTOR` and `VBAR`. Reading from which is a privileged operation. In *PowerPC* it can be at two fixed locations determined by the `MSR` register, again a privileged one. In *MIPS* there is really no *IVT* and the location is fixed. *Anyway in order to execute privileged instructions you need to make a Kernel Module, root is not enough.*</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup>
To be accurate here one would need to bit a little bit too technical, introducing the concept of *MMU*, address translation, instruction crafting, trampolines and process context (your routine is essentially isolated as it could be run under any other process context).</sub>

<sub><sup>4</sup> 
It's worth noting that "working against the OS* is usually an uphill slope that pay little or nothing, rather than changing the carefully crafted OS structures, it's better to use the relevant APIs.</sub>